# force tty creation for crontab job

Tags: java, linux, ssh, expect, tty

I've been coding a litte bash script which connects on several distant servers, then execute a java CLI program through a few expect instructions.

It goes like this :

```
bash script
  expect
  ssh to server using public keys
    expect ...
    expect ...
    log_file my_file (everything displayed on the screen is now redirected to my_file)
    expect ...
    log_file (closing my_file)
    exit
exit
```

When I execute my script manually everything runs OK.
When I execute it through crontab, the file my_file is empty.

I found out that cron jobs don't have a tty attached and that PATH isn't the same as usually

My question is : is there a way to force the creation/allocation of a tty to my cronjob?

I've tried using the -t and -tt option with ssh but no result.
redirecting standard output on different levels of the script didn't work.

Also, I can't install screen (which could have helped, maybe) and "script" isn't writing anything either.

Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 0):

You can check the cron tab log for erros and make sure the full path is given for the command to be executed.

Comment: Just checked : no error in the cron logs. i've check also if there are uncomplete path in my script to avoid errors regarding the execution in crontab with its limited PATH but everything looks OK. I really think the problem is more about the missing tty though.